# Given a comment field, how to detect programming code (ruby/js...) and style with a code block?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm building an app where you can submit a comment to a rails server.

Is there a way to automatically find and wrap the submitted code inside a code block allow me to style the code nicely?

Thanks

Comment: Or maybe this needs to be done with jQuery?

Answer (score 0):

You can use http://softwaremaniacs.org/soft/highlight/en/ that detect syntax in `<pre></pre>` tags and add coloring to them. Try this out.

Comment: Thanks but I'm interested in finding a way that does not require the user wrapping code in tags... I'd like to make this automatic.

Comment: For me it's imposible to do that. Maybe you are looking for some light markup language.